# Printing to a Local Shared Printer When the Network is down

Tags: windows, cmd, printing

I have some legacy application logic that sends files to an attached printer using a DOS copy command:

copy fileToPrint \myLocalComputerName\printerShareName

The problem is that even though the application is running on the computer that's physically attached to the printer since it's using a network "share" it requires the network be available.  If the network isn't available DOS throws a network unavailable error.

How can I code this so I don't have the network dependency? (preferably without re-architecting the entire file based print logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the following article which uses a loopback network adapter to access the local share when the network is unavailable.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128143915/http://geekswithblogs.net/dtotzke/articles/26204.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? (Old DOS trick)

```
type myfile.txt > prn
```

This should work if the printer in question is the default printer on the PC.

Comment: It's not the default printer. :-(

Comment: OK.  Sorry I don't have a better answer.

Comment: But, it looks like the same trick might work with LPT1. I'll check in the morning. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: That didn't work directly, but I found that the print command did--for LPT1.  However, that didn't work with my newer USB printer.  However, found a solution (will post as separate answer.)  Thanks for the this idea however--upvote!